# Cloud functions - get document of document reference

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document snapshot with a field `renter`, which is of type `DocumentReference`. How can I get the document referenced by `renter`? I have tried:

`let snap = await snapshot.renter.get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the **document** referenced by the `renter` field of type [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference), just do as follows:

```
snapshot.get("renter").get().then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(error => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

or

```
let snap = await snapshot.get("renter").get();
```